# Starting Apache - "unable to open logs"

Tags: apache2

The disk my server is on was full and Apache couldn't create logfiles anymore. I cleaned the disk and it has enough free disk space now, but still no logfiles are created. I tought to try restarting Apache (hoping that the issue would be solved by that, if somebody has some other bright idea, be welcome...), but that gave the following error messsage:

```
# /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k restart
[Tue Jun 06 11:58:33 2017] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:443 has no VirtualHosts
httpd not running, trying to start
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
```

The "unable to open logs" is the reason I wanted to restart Apache, but it still isn't working... anybody have an idea what I could do?

Trying to solve the "make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80,", I tried

```
# /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k stop
```

This gives me this message ...

```
[Tue Jun 06 14:00:14 2017] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:443 has no VirtualHosts
httpd (no pid file) not running
```

but when I try

```
# ps aux | grep apache
```

I get ...

```
apache1267  0.2  0.0  31816  7548 ?S13:53   0:01 /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
apache1535  0.1  0.0  31520  7320 ?S13:54   0:00 /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
apache1541  0.1  0.0  30224  6016 ?S13:54   0:00 /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
apache1928  0.1  0.0  30744  6440 ?S13:56   0:00 /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
apache2075  0.2  0.0  31268  6732 ?S13:57   0:00 /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
apache2508  0.2  0.0  30624  6284 ?S14:00   0:00 /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
apache2693  0.3  0.0  30236  5724 ?S14:01   0:00 /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
apache2718  0.0  0.0  30368  5788 ?S14:01   0:00 /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
apache2722  0.0  0.0  30068  4968 ?S14:01   0:00 /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
apache2754  0.2  0.0  31272  6516 ?S14:02   0:00 /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
apache2780  0.1  0.0  30232  5688 ?S14:02   0:00 /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
apache2808  0.2  0.0  30496  6016 ?S14:02   0:00 /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
apache2903  0.0  0.0  29928  4748 ?S14:02   0:00 /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
apache2912  0.0  0.0  29792  3944 ?S14:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
apache2915  0.0  0.0  29792  3772 ?S14:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
apache2916  0.0  0.0  29792  3772 ?S14:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
root  2921  0.0  0.0   3348   844 pts/0S+   14:03   0:00 grep apache
root 18281  0.0  0.0  29792  5000 ?Ss   May29   0:21 /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
```

Comment: use `httpd -t`. this shows where the error is

Comment: Please what Ubuntu server version is this?

Comment: ~# /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -t -k restart
[Tue Jun 06 13:42:20 2017] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:443 has no VirtualHosts
Syntax OK

Comment: I edited the original post to explain more in detail what I have done so far...